# How to make a blacklist of URLs for my website

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn, custom-font, blacklist

I have a website based on a themed bootstrap CSS file.  This CSS file is hosted on a CDN, so I can't edit it.  I really like this custom bootstrap file, but it loads a font almost 30kb, which is too much for me.

I basically want to add something to my HTML file that will act just like a hosts file, like an ad blocker.  How can I edit my html file from block/blacklist these URLS or prevent it from downloading?

https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/1YwB1sO8YE1Lyjf12WNiUA.woff2
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Lato

Comment: Why not simply have a copy of the CSS on your own server that does not link to the font files?

Comment: The CDN is very fast, at least twice as fast as my hosting server.  Also, it saves bandwidth.

Comment: Then I don't understand why bother about the 30kb font? ... Which size is the CSS?

Comment: I just need to blacklist a url in my html code.  Shouldn't it only take one or two lines of code?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm so nit picky, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @LGSon the bootstrap CSS file is 26.6 kb

Comment: You can't do that, and no point bother since it is not on your server ..., and if you still want to not have the font loaded (which you still haven't told why), you need to fork the CSS and either try upload it to the CDN (or any other CDN) or have it on your own server.